# IOS: fill a NSMutableArray with some NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, object, nsmutablearray

In my project I must fill an NSMutableArray with some NSMutable array, my code is:

This is a method

```
-(void) fill {
[smallArray removeAllObjects]; //when I call this method I delete every object inside smallArray

for {
//in this for I fill with some object a NSMutableArray that I called "smallArray"

[smallArray addObject:object];
}

//outside this for I have my NSMutable bigArray that I must fill with smallArray
[bigArray = ?????];
```

How can I fill this bigArray?

Comment: If i understang correctly you must have an array that contains other arrays?     [bigArray addObject:smallArray];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlesss I'm missing something, simply use the `addObject:` method (as you're already doing for the small array), supplying the smallArray to add.

i.e.: `[bigArray addObject:smallArray];`

If however you just want to add the *objects* from smallArray into the bigArray, then you could use the `addObjectsFromArray:` method...

```
[bigArray addObjectsFromArray:smallArray];
```

...which will append the objects after any existing ones within bigArray. For more information, check out the relevant section of the [NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Comment: I tried to use addObject [bigArray addObject:smallArray]; but if I write NSLog(@"array number:%d",[bigArray count]); in my console the result is ever 0.....why?

Comment: @blackguardian Are you sure the smallArray is being populated correctly? (What happens if you carry out the same NSLog on the smallArray just prior to calling the addObject on the bigArray?)

Comment: I understand my problem, I didn't make the alloc of my array...Now it's all ok, thanks

Comment: @blackguardian Cool - glad you're making progress. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i understang correctly you must have an array that contains other arrays?

```
[bigArray addObject:smallArray];
```

Then you can access the array like this

```
NSMutableArray * arrayfromArray =[bigArray objectAtIndex: someIndex];
```